# How to prove this problem about the convergence of the sequence?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $a_n>0$ and $b_n>0$ for $n=1,2,3,\dotsb.$
Suppose that $\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_{n}}\leq\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$for $n=1,2,3,\dotsb.$
Show that if $\{a_n\}$ is convergent, then $\{b_n\}$ is convergent. (I think I can understand it if $\{a_n\}$ is monotonic, in general I cannot figure out this problem.)

Comment: What are your ideas? Do include them in your post

Comment: Note that multplying inequalities from $n=1$ to $n=m-1$ gives $\frac{b_m}{b_1}\leq\frac{a_m}{a_1}$, so $0<b_m\leq c\cdot a_m$ where $c=\frac{b_1}{a_1}$. Can you continue now?

Comment: Thanks and I think I know how to do it.

Comment: Sorry, I realised that I actually misread the problem. I thought we need to prove that if series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ is convergent, then so is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}b_k$.

Comment: Please take a look of my proof, I think it is clear to see that it is true when we consider the series. But what about the sequence?

Answer (score 1):

Note that multiplying inequalities from $n=1$ to $n=n-1$, i.e. 
    $$\frac{b_2}{b_1}\frac{b_3}{b_2}\dotsb\frac{b_n}{b_{n-1}}\leq \frac{a_2}{a_1}\frac{a_3}{a_2}\dotsb\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}\Longrightarrow \frac{b_n}{b_1} \leq\frac{a_n}{a_1}$$ which implies $$0<\frac{b_n}{a_n}\leq \frac{b_1}{a_1}$$ for $n=1,2,3\dotsb.$ And $$\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}\leq\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \Longrightarrow \frac{b_{n+1}}{a_{n+1}}\leq\frac{b_{n}}{a_{n}}$$ for $n=2,3,4\dotsb.$  Then we denote that $c_n=\frac{b_n}{a_n}$ then $\{c_n\}$ is a bounded monotonic decreasing sequence, which is convergent. And since $\{a_n\}$ is convergent, then by the theorem, we obtain $b_n=a_nc_n$ is convergent.

Comment: The idea is from @richrow